# Javascript form validator function not working properly

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I have been trying to make this function work for two hours now, but am not able to find where the error is.

This is behaving unexpectedly.

When any of the field in the form is filled, the form is posted to php file,
and shows errors (as expected) only when all fields are left empty, i.e.the 5 errors.

But when any of the 6 fields is filled, the form is posted irrespective of other errors in the form.

Please help me validating this form.

`error` is the information of errors I will show to users.
`errors` is number of errors found.

`JavaScript function`

```
function formValidator(){

    var elementValue = document.getElementById("first-name").value;
    var elementName = document.getElementById("first-name");
    var errors = 0;
    var error = " ";

    if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue== NULL){
        error = "First Name shouldn't be left empty.";
        errors = 1;
    }

    var elementValue = document.getElementById("last-name").value;
    var elementName = document.getElementById("last-name");

    if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue== NULL){
        if (errors == 0){
            error = "Last Name shouldn't be left empty.";
        }
        else{
            error += "<br>Last Name shouldn't be left empty.";
        }
        errors+=1;
    }
    var elementValue = document.getElementById("email-for-registration").value;
    var elementName = document.getElementById("email-for-registration");
    var email_err = "false";
    if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue== NULL){
        email_err = "true";
    }
    var elementValue = document.getElementById("phone-for-registration").value;
    if ((elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue== NULL) && email_err == "true"){
        if (errors == 0){
            error = "Both email and contact cannot be left empty.";
        }
        else{
            error += "<br>Both email and contact cannot be left empty.";
        }
        errors+=1;
    }
    var elementValue = document.getElementById("password-for-registration").value;
    var elementName = document.getElementById("password-for-registration");
    if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue== NULL){
        if (errors == 0){
            error = "Password shouldn't be left empty.\nSelect a strong password atleast 6 characters long.";
        }
        else{
            error += "<br>Password shouldn't be left empty.Select a strong password atleast 6 characters long.";
        }
        errors+=1;
    }
    else if (elementValue.length<6){
        if (errors == 0){
            error = "Password less than 6 characters aren't allowed for security reasons.";
        }
        else{
            error += "<br>Password less than 6 characters aren't allowed for security reasons.";
        }
        errors+=1;
    }
    email_err = document.getElementById("confirm-password-for-registration").value;
    var elementName = document.getElementById("confirm-password-for-registration");
    if (elementValue != email_err){
        if (errors == 0){
            error = "The password to confirm doesn't match with your desired password.";
        }
        else{
            error += "<br>The password to confirm doesn't match with your desired password.";
        }
        errors+=1;
    }
    var elementValue = document.getElementById("agreed-for-registration");
    var elementName = document.getElementById("agreed-for-registration");
    if (!elementValue.checked){
        if (errors == 0){
        error = "Please go through our <a href=''>Terms and Conditions</a>, and make sure you agree to continue.";
         document.getElementById("agreed-for-registration").focus();
        }
        else{
            error += "<br>Please go through our <a href=''>Terms and Conditions</a>, and make sure you agree to continue.";
        }
        errors+=1;
    }


    alert(errors);

    if (errors > 1){
        document.getElementById("form_errors").innerHTML = "<h4 style='color:red;'>Please remove the following errors from form to continue.</h4>";
        document.getElementById("form_errors").innerHTML += "<h5>" + error + "</h5><br>";
        return false;
    } else if (errors == 1){
        alert(error);
        elementName.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (errors == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Function called here.

```
<form name="registration" class="deco_blu_form" action="<?=$base_url;?>forms/confirm-registration/members.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formValidator();">
```

Please ask if any other information, code or explanation is required.

Comment: Do you get the `alert(errors);`  ?

Comment: @Sergio yes but as I said only when all fields are empty, i get 5 errors. otherwise nothing.

Comment: I wonder if the fact you are using `NULL` instead of `null` is the problem.

Comment: Do not rely on client side validation

Comment: Give different `elementValue`, like `elementValue1`, `elementValue2` to the var name

Comment: @php_nub_qq okay. But i feel its better to show some errors to the user there itself instead of sending information to server and then loading page again and all.

Comment: Don't use `var` every time you re-assign your `elementValue` and `elementName` variables.

Comment: @rosscj2533 thanks for pointing that out, but I wasn't using it but did that to ensure if the var elementValue wasnt being reassigned or something.:) just trying all things.

Comment: @RobH that was it. Thanks a lot. But is `NULL` not allowed?

Comment: @optim js is case sensitive - so no you're not allowed `NULL` :) Also, it would be far easier to gather your messages in an array and then use `join` to add the `<br>`s - or use an unordered list and not use `<br>`s for spacing.

Comment: @optim - in fact, it may be worth you posting your working code to codereview.stackexchange.com - you'd get some useful feedback on coding style.

Comment: @php_nub_qq i thought about it and saw your point. It was nice of you to draw my attention towards this. I would also apply server side validation now:)

Comment: @optim Always happy to help. I would also recommend in future not to waste your time building client side validation, instead have your server side one be called using ajax if you want to 'show some errors' :P

Comment: @RobH Hey great suggestions there. Thanks. I did not know about codereview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kZVju/3/)**

You need to have `elementValue === "NULL"` or `elementValue == null`

I put `console.log` instead of alert and `onblur` trigger just for me to debug easier.

So the full code is:

```
function formValidator() {

var elementValue = document.getElementById("first-name").value;
var elementName = document.getElementById("first-name");
var errors = 0;
var error = " ";

if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue === "NULL") {
    error = "First Name shouldn't be left empty.";
    errors = 1;
}

var elementValue = document.getElementById("last-name").value;
var elementName = document.getElementById("last-name");

if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue === "NULL") {
    if (errors == 0) {
        error = "Last Name shouldn't be left empty.";
    } else {
        error += "<br>Last Name shouldn't be left empty.";
    }
    errors += 1;
}
var elementValue = document.getElementById("email-for-registration").value;
var elementName = document.getElementById("email-for-registration");
var email_err = "false";
if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue === "NULL") {
    email_err = "true";
}
var elementValue = document.getElementById("phone-for-registration").value;
if ((elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue === "NULL") && email_err == "true") {
    if (errors == 0) {
        error = "Both email and contact cannot be left empty.";
    } else {
        error += "<br>Both email and contact cannot be left empty.";
    }
    errors += 1;
}
var elementValue = document.getElementById("password-for-registration").value;
var elementName = document.getElementById("password-for-registration");
if (elementValue == "" || elementValue == " " || elementValue === "NULL") {
    if (errors == 0) {
        error = "Password shouldn't be left empty.\nSelect a strong password atleast 6 characters long.";
    } else {
        error += "<br>Password shouldn't be left empty.Select a strong password atleast 6 characters long.";
    }
    errors += 1;
} else if (elementValue.length < 6) {
    if (errors == 0) {
        error = "Password less than 6 characters aren't allowed for security reasons.";
    } else {
        error += "<br>Password less than 6 characters aren't allowed for security reasons.";
    }
    errors += 1;
}
email_err = document.getElementById("confirm-password-for-registration").value;
var elementName = document.getElementById("confirm-password-for-registration");
if (elementValue != email_err) {
    if (errors == 0) {
        error = "The password to confirm doesn't match with your desired password.";
    } else {
        error += "<br>The password to confirm doesn't match with your desired password.";
    }
    errors += 1;
}
var elementValue = document.getElementById("agreed-for-registration");
var elementName = document.getElementById("agreed-for-registration");
if (!elementValue.checked) {
    if (errors == 0) {
        error = "Please go through our <a href=''>Terms and Conditions</a>, and make sure you agree to continue.";
        document.getElementById("agreed-for-registration").focus();
    } else {
        error += "<br>Please go through our <a href=''>Terms and Conditions</a>, and make sure you agree to continue.";
    }
    errors += 1;
}


console.log(errors)

if (errors > 1) {
    document.getElementById("form_errors").innerHTML = "<h4 style='color:red;'>Please remove the following errors from form to continue.</h4>";
    document.getElementById("form_errors").innerHTML += "<h5>" + error + "</h5><br>";
    return false;
} else if (errors == 1) {
    alert(error);
    elementName.focus();
    return false;
} else if (errors == 0) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I count the following fields:

1. first-name
2. last-name
3. email-for-registration
4. phone-for-registration
5. password-for-registration
6. confirm-password-for-registration
7. agreed-for-registration

Just in case if you do something with the absolute value.

I have built a small prove-of-concept script and encountered that this script doesn't work, if you don't have an element with id #form_errors. Could this be your problem? This way the call for `document.getElementById("form_errors")` would result in undefined, and the function would not return `false`.

The same check for undefined elements holds of course for the other fields, too ;)

Comment: Sorry i had them. Thanks for effort. I have got the solution.